# How to get google contacts username, email and profile picture?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I need help in getting the google contact details `username`, `email`, `picture`.  This code is working fine fetching email:

```javascript
var config = {
  'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  //'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener',
  'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
};

gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
  var authParams = gapi.auth.getToken(); // from Google oAuth
  authParams.alt = 'json';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: authParams,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    }
  });
});
```

This data display only user email address but I also want username and profile pic.

Is this posssible? Please help me.

Comment: From what I understand of your question, you are looking to get the username, email and profile picture for the contacts of the authenticated user.  If this is the case, have you looked at the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)?  With [proper scopes](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#connection-scopes) requested, you should be able to get the data you seek if the user agrees to the OAuth consent screen.